# Ignore directories with .dockerignore or volume?

Tags: docker

I want to create a basic Docker web-server (nginx) container.  I don't want the logfiles to be part of the aufs tracked files (when I do `docker diff`, I don't want my logfiles to show up)

I can achieve this now by declaring `/var/log/nginx` as a volume (`-v`) when I `docker run` the container.  I'm not linking the volume to a directory in the host, or any other container. Its just a volume known to the web-server container only.

I am also reading that there is a way via `.dockerignore` to exclude the directory when I initially build the image for the container.

Which approach is recommended for a case like this?

Answer (score 3):

Your solution with volumes seems to be the right approach.

`.dockerignore` solves a different problem. You can use that to exclude files and directories from the `docker build`, i.e. theses files are not sent to the docker daemon when `docker build .` is invoked, speeding up the build process.

Taken from [here](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/)